# Mysql not letting me set value to CURRENT_TIME using an index

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a row using an index. But for some reason it keeps giving me an error.

Would any one be able to help resolve this. I can't get it to work. 
Below is my query

```
UPDATE invalid_login_attempts SET attempts = 4 last_attempt=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id = 2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you missing a ","? (`SET attempts = 4, last_attempt=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma between the two expressions in the `set` clause:

```
UPDATE invalid_login_attempts 
SET    attempts = 4, -- This comma was missing
       last_attempt = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE  id = 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't believe I skipped that!